# Resharper and XAML StaticResources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

I have one problem with Resharper and XAML StaticResources.

It seems that Resharper cannot handle Resources from another library.

Example:
I have `App.xaml` with some resources like

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Accent1" Color="#0088C9"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Now I'm trying to reference this resource in a project, where `App.xaml` is defined - everything works file (Resharpers intellisense is working. No error shown after typing resource name)

Now, I'm trying to do the same for another project (in same solution and of course referenced by main project).

And the problem is that:

- Resharper intellisense does not see my resources
- After typing proper Resource name it still shows error, that resource is not found

After disabling Resharper and using VS 2015 intellisense it works properly.

So the question is:
- Is there a way to fix it?
- If not. Is there a way to disable XAML intellisense in Resharper (but left all other features of Resharper active)

Comment: Sad that they still didn't fix it, it's been reported for years.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I got rid of the issue by adding the following to my `.editorconfig` for the solution:

```
resharper_xaml_static_resource_not_resolved_highlighting = silent
```

You will still get build errors from visual studio if you try to use a non-existing reference, so it should be fairly safe to use the above.

The various resharper code inspections are documented here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_XAML.html